# Will the water level keep rising up after attaining terminal velocity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, superfluidity

Suppose I have an infinitely long container of water and I dropped a metal ball into it.

Initially, the water level will rise up due to displacement of volume. But will it keep rising when the whole body is inside water?

Also, does the presence of viscosity make any difference to the answer?

Comment: What does a rise in water level have to do with terminal velocity? Don't take this the wrong way. I'm genuinely curious how you came to this conclusion.

Comment: @Mechanic7 terminal velocity is achieved when the body has fallen a substantial depth. Just wanted to say that will the water level keep rising even after the body is submerged?

Comment: I can't think of any phenomenon that should lead to the rise of the water level after the body has fully submerged. Maybe if you throw the body in the water with some force, the water may cause a momentary splash, but other than that, it should not cause any continuous increase of water level.

Comment: A similar question was asked in JEE Advanced 2009 in which it asked if the gravitational potential energy of water will keep rising continuously.

Comment: After some thinking, I came to the conclusion that it should, to keep in accordance with the energy law. When the metal ball is dropped, it loses potential energy. The water level has to rise up continuously. This was when the liquid was non viscous.

Comment: "*When the metal ball is dropped, it loses potential energy*". No

Comment: Why? I am talking about the metal ball earth system

Comment: @Mechanic7 “*I can't think of any phenomenon that should lead to the rise of the water level after the body has fully submerged.*” As the ball falls through the water, it heats it through drag. The thermal expansion coefficient of water is generally nonzero.

Comment: @Chemomechanics The increase of temperature due to the object falling through the tube will be insignificant, especially for an infinite tube. Unless the body travels with a very high velocity, it should not cause any increase of water level.

Comment: @Mechanic7 Quite the opposite; for a well-insulated tube, the effect is cumulative. I have no idea if this is a nuance the question’s author intended to focus on. But it is where the potential energy goes.

Comment: I considered a conductive tube. But you are absolutely correct that the potential energy would increase the internal energy of the system, and hence it's temperature.